# How to filter list of lists using streams on the basis of a value in a list?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<List<Double>>`. I want to filter rows on the basis of an index i.e. if value of an element at index 4 is less than 0.2 then, skip that row? The resultant `List<List<Double>>` should be smaller or same as the input one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Stream.filter`. Note you have to select the rows which you want to take, not the rows which you want to skip:

```
List<List<Double>> input = ...;

List<List<Double>> result = input.stream()
              .filter(row -> row.get(4) >= 0.2)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

An alternative to the Stream API would be in-place modification using `Collection.removeIf`:

```
List<List<Double>> input = ...;

input.removeIf(row -> row.get(4) < 0.2);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, there was a typo in the question thats why it wasn't clear.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: `removeIf` changes my original list. I don't want that, but it is new information. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lambda expression, and that would be fine, but for something a little more reusable, you might consider using your own `Predicate`, for example

```
public class SubElementPredict implements Predicate<List<Double>> {

    private int index;
    private double value;

    public SubElementPredict(int index, double value) {
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(List<Double> t) {
        return value < t.get(index);
    }

}
```

Then you could just do something like...

```
List<List<Double>> values = new ArrayList<>(25);
values.add(Arrays.asList(new Double[]{1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d}));
values.add(Arrays.asList(new Double[]{6d, 7d, 8d, 9d, 10d}));
values.add(Arrays.asList(new Double[]{11d, 12d, 13d, 14d, 15d}));

int index = 2;
double value = 8d;
List<List<Double>> filtered = values
            .stream()
            .filter(new SubElementPredict(index, value))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
for (List<Double> sub : filtered) {
    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

Which outputs

```
[11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0]
```

Now, if you wanted to get even more adventures, you might even be able to do something like...

```
public class SubElementPredict<V extends Comparable> implements Predicate<List<V>> {

    private int index;
    private V value;

    public SubElementPredict(int index, V value) {
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(List<V> t) {
        return value.compareTo(t.get(index)) <= 0;
    }

}
```

And now, you can use any `List` of `Comparable` values

Comment: So, basically what you have done is that you used a user-defined function instead of a lambda expression.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey Yeah, pretty much.  You could write a method as well, passing in the values you want to compare, or re-use the `Predict` with other `Stream` functions, but that comes down to your needs ;)

Comment: Hmm, these classes do not add anything to the one-liner contained in the `test` implementation, besides the necessary boilerplate code, so I don’t see the point of writing these named classes instead of just using a lambda expression. If reusability of code fragments like `t -> value < t.get(index)` was a concern, it questioned the entire idea of lambda expressions…

Comment: @Holger Some days, I do. But this comes down to preferences and needs. Personally, the expended expression provides greater readability (for a noob like me whose still trying to get their head around the api and it's requirements).  That said, if you prefer baffling people with your brilliance you are of course free to do so.  Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the desire to write less code, but for me, readability and understandability is also important and as I'm still getting my head into this space, expanding the code into something I can surmise about is important

Comment: I’m not objecting the usefulness of named classes. But I think the expression here is small enough to be justify a lambda usage and since it’s about using the `Stream` API which most developers learn together with the lambda expressions as both are new to Java 8, I don’t think that the result is obscure to the average developer.

Comment: @Holger I disagree with you either. I've had the misfortune of trying to learn entirely new API's where developers have chosen to use lambda expressions as part of their basic coding, which has degraded the readability and understandability for me, coming into the API from the outside.  The importance here is, there's more then one way to skin ;).  I don't discount there power, but when they hide important information about the API (like the fact that's a predict and the type value been passed to (this is not the best example)), I want to beat a developers head against their screen ;)